# Can't seem to save Enum values from form

Tags: razor, drop-down-menu

I can't find the cause of a error I keep geting. I'm getting values from a enum to a dropdownlist but I don't know if that's the issue since then exception occurs only in browser, and not in VS.

View:

```
@model HiltiHaninge.Models.CellModel
@using HiltiHaninge.Models
@{
var db = new HiltiHaninge.Models.HiltiHaningeContext();
var users = db.UserProfiles.ToList();
}

<h2>@ViewBag.Title</h2>

@using (Html.BeginForm("CreateCell", "Schema", FormMethod.Post))
{
@Html.AntiForgeryToken()
@Html.ValidationSummary(true)

<fieldset>
    <legend>Ny träning</legend>

    <div class="editor-label">
        <p>Tid från:</p>
    </div>
    <div class="editor-field">
        @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.TimeFromHour, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "main_content_fieldset_text" })
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.TimeFromHour)
        @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.TimeFromMinute, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "main_content_fieldset_text" })
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.TimeFromMinute)
    </div>

    <div class="editor-label">
        <p>Tid till:</p>
    </div>
    <div class="editor-field">
        @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.TimeToHour, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "main_content_fieldset_text" })
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.TimeToHour)
        @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.TimeToMinute, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "main_content_fieldset_text" })
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.TimeToMinute)
    </div>

    <div class="editor-label">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Discipline, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "main_content_fieldset_text" })
    </div>
    <div class="editor-field">
        @Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.Discipline, Enum.GetValues(typeof(Discplines)).Cast<Discplines>().Select(x => new SelectListItem { Text = x.ToString(), Value = ((int)x).ToString() }))
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.Discipline)
    </div>

    <div class="editor-label">
        @Html.LabelFor(m => m.Level, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "main_content_fieldset_text" })
    </div>
    <div class="editor-field">
        @Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.Level, Enum.GetValues(typeof(Levels)).Cast<Levels>().Select(x => new SelectListItem { Text = x.ToString(), Value = ((int)x).ToString() }))
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.Level)
    </div>

    <div class="editor-label">
        @Html.LabelFor(m => m.Coach, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "main_tcontent_fieldset_text" })
    </div>
    <div class="editor-field">
        @Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.Coach, new SelectList(users, "UserName", "UserName"))
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.Coach)
    </div>

    <input type="submit" value="Skapa" />
</fieldset>
}

@section Scripts {
@Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jqueryval")
 }
```

And controller:

```
 public ActionResult CreateCell()
    {
        return View();
    }

    [HttpPost]
    [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    public ActionResult CreateCell(CellModel cell, Days day)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            using (var db = new HiltiHaningeContext())
            {
                var schedule = new DaySchedule();
                var c = new CellEntity
                    {
                        TimeFromHour = cell.TimeFromHour,
                        TimeFromMinute = cell.TimeFromMinute,
                        TimeToHour = cell.TimeToHour,
                        TimeToMinute = cell.TimeToMinute,
                        Discipline = cell.Discipline,
                        Coach = cell.Coach
                    };
                schedule.Bookings.Add(c);
                //schedule.Day = day;

                db.CellEntities.Add(c);
                db.DaySchedules.Add(schedule);
                db.SaveChanges();
                return RedirectToAction("Index", "Schema");
            }
        }
        else
        {
            ModelState.Clear();
        }
        return View(cell);
    }
```

I crashes after clicking "Skapa" without any further information, and reaching breakpoints.

Unable to cast object of type 'System.Int32' to type 'System.String'.

Please help, because I'm really stuck here.

StackTrace upon request:

```
[InvalidCastException: Unable to cast object of type 'System.Int32' to type 'System.String'.]
System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.StringLengthAttribute.IsValid(Object value) +46
System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.ValidationAttribute.IsValid(Object value, ValidationContext validationContext) +115
System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.ValidationAttribute.GetValidationResult(Object value, ValidationContext validationContext) +29
System.Web.Mvc.<Validate>d__15.MoveNext() +158
System.Web.Mvc.<Validate>d__1.MoveNext() +311
System.Web.Mvc.DefaultModelBinder.OnModelUpdated(ControllerContext controllerContext, ModelBindingContext bindingContext) +135
System.Web.Mvc.DefaultModelBinder.BindComplexElementalModel(ControllerContext controllerContext, ModelBindingContext bindingContext, Object model) +66
System.Web.Mvc.DefaultModelBinder.BindComplexModel(ControllerContext controllerContext, ModelBindingContext bindingContext) +1315
System.Web.Mvc.DefaultModelBinder.BindModel(ControllerContext controllerContext, ModelBindingContext bindingContext) +416
System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.GetParameterValue(ControllerContext controllerContext, ParameterDescriptor parameterDescriptor) +317
System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.GetParameterValues(ControllerContext controllerContext, ActionDescriptor actionDescriptor) +117
System.Web.Mvc.Async.<>c__DisplayClass25.<BeginInvokeAction>b__1e(AsyncCallback asyncCallback, Object asyncState) +446
System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncResult`1.Begin(AsyncCallback callback, Object state, Int32 timeout) +130
System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncControllerActionInvoker.BeginInvokeAction(ControllerContext controllerContext, String actionName, AsyncCallback callback, Object state) +302
System.Web.Mvc.<>c__DisplayClass1d.<BeginExecuteCore>b__17(AsyncCallback asyncCallback, Object asyncState) +30
System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncResult`1.Begin(AsyncCallback callback, Object state, Int32 timeout) +130
System.Web.Mvc.Controller.BeginExecuteCore(AsyncCallback callback, Object state) +381
System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncResult`1.Begin(AsyncCallback callback, Object state, Int32 timeout) +130
System.Web.Mvc.Controller.BeginExecute(RequestContext requestContext, AsyncCallback callback, Object state) +317
  System.Web.Mvc.Controller.System.Web.Mvc.Async.IAsyncController.BeginExecute(RequestContext requestContext, AsyncCallback callback, Object state) +15
System.Web.Mvc.<>c__DisplayClass8.<BeginProcessRequest>b__2(AsyncCallback asyncCallback, Object asyncState) +71
System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncResult`1.Begin(AsyncCallback callback, Object state, Int32 timeout) +130
System.Web.Mvc.MvcHandler.BeginProcessRequest(HttpContextBase httpContext, AsyncCallback callback, Object state) +249
System.Web.Mvc.MvcHandler.BeginProcessRequest(HttpContext httpContext, AsyncCallback callback, Object state) +49
System.Web.Mvc.MvcHandler.System.Web.IHttpAsyncHandler.BeginProcessRequest(HttpContext context, AsyncCallback cb, Object extraData) +16
System.Web.CallHandlerExecutionStep.System.Web.HttpApplication.IExecutionStep.Execute() +301
System.Web.HttpApplication.ExecuteStep(IExecutionStep step, Boolean& completedSynchronously) +155
```

and finally model:

```
 public class CellEntity
 {
    public virtual int TimeFromMinute { get; set; }
    public virtual int TimeFromHour { get; set; }
    public virtual int TimeToMinute { get; set; }
    public virtual int TimeToHour { get; set; }
    [Key]
    [DatabaseGeneratedAttribute(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
    public virtual Days Day { get; set; }
    public virtual Discplines Discipline { get; set; }
    //public virtual UserProfile Coach { get; set; }
    public virtual string Coach { get; set; }
    public virtual Levels Level { get; set; }
}
public enum Levels
{
    Nybörjare,
    Avancerad,
    Barn
}
public enum Days
{
    Måndag,
    Tisdag,
    Onsdag,
    Torsdag,
    Fredag,
    Lördag,
    Söndag
}
public enum Discplines
{
    BJJ,
    Thai,
    SW,
    MMA,
    Mix
}
public class DaySchedule
{
    [Key]
    [DatabaseGeneratedAttribute(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
    public virtual Days Day { get; set; }
    public virtual List<CellEntity> Bookings { get; set; }
}
public class CellModel 
{
    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Måste fylla i från vilken timme.")]
    //[StringLength(2, ErrorMessage = "Måste vara ett giltigt tvåsiffrigt klockslag.", MinimumLength = 2)]
    [RegularExpression(@"^[0-9]*$", ErrorMessage = "Endast siffror tillåtna.")]
    [Display(Name = "Timme från")]
    public int TimeFromHour { get; set; }

    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Måste fylla i från vilka minuter.")]
    //[StringLength(2, ErrorMessage = "Måste vara ett giltigt tvåsiffrigt klockslag.", MinimumLength = 2)]
    [RegularExpression(@"^[0-9]*$", ErrorMessage = "Endast siffror tillåtna.")]
    [Display(Name = "Minut från")]
    public int TimeFromMinute { get; set; }

    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Måste fylla i till vilken timme.")]
    //[StringLength(2, ErrorMessage = "Måste vara ett giltigt tvåsiffrigt klockslag.", MinimumLength = 2)]
    [RegularExpression(@"^[0-9]*$", ErrorMessage = "Endast siffror tillåtna.")]
    [Display(Name = "Timme till")]
    public int TimeToHour { get; set; }

    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Måste fylla i till vilka minuter.")]
    //[StringLength(2, ErrorMessage = "Måste vara ett giltigt tvåsiffrigt klockslag.", MinimumLength = 2)]
    [RegularExpression(@"^[0-9]*$", ErrorMessage = "Endast siffror tillåtna.")]
    [Display(Name = "Minut till")]
    public int TimeToMinute { get; set; }

    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Måste fylla i vilken disciplin det gäller (stil).")]
    [Display(Name = "Disciplin")]
    public Discplines Discipline { get; set; }

    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Måste välja en tränare till passet.")]
    [Display(Name = "Tränare")]
    public string Coach { get; set; }

    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Måste välja en nivå på passet.")]
    [Display(Name = "Nivå")]
    public Levels Level { get; set; }
 }
```

Comment: Could you post the stack trace from the error?

Comment: Done. Couldn't get it correct though..

Comment: Looks like a Validation attribute is causing an issue in your `CellModel` class, specifically a `StringLength` attribute.

Comment: Thats amazing. Why does [StringLength(2, ErrorMessage = "Wrong", MinimumLength = 2)] not work?

Comment: What's the type of the property that is on? I'm guessing... `int`?

Comment: Yes. And I get another exception. Updating the question with model: The parameters dictionary contains a null entry for parameter 'day' of non-nullable type 'HiltiHaninge.Models.Days' for method 'System.Web.Mvc.ActionResult CreateCell(HiltiHaninge.Models.CellModel, HiltiHaninge.Models.Days)' in 'HiltiHaninge.Controllers.SchemaController'. An optional parameter must be a reference type, a nullable type, or be declared as an optional parameter.
Parameter name: parameters

Comment: @DaveParsons I can see what the error is, but not how to solve it... any ideas?

Comment: where do you expect this to come from  public ActionResult CreateCell(CellModel cell, Days day) your Days day

Comment: `Days` is an enum, which cannot be `null` you have a few options; 1) Always post a valid `Days` value to the controller 2) Provide a default value in the action method e.g. `public ActionResult CreateCell(CellModel cell, Days day = Days.Måndag)` 3) Use a `Nullable<Day>` as the parameter (usually using the shorthand `Days? day` syntax - this will mean you can check in the action method for a value (`days.HasValue`) and use it (`days.Value`) if it is present.